# reg key check causing crash

Tags: .net, vb.net, registry, regedit

I have this function here that checks Whether or not it is in registry and returns true if it is, false if it's not. However, it crashes every time right around

```
R = My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True)
```

Here is the entire function:

```
Private Function CheckKey2() As Boolean
Dim R As RegistryKey
    Dim V() As String
    Dim O As String = vbNullString
    R = My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True)
    V = R.GetValueNames()
    R.Close()

    For Each Str As String In V
        O = O & Str & "|"
    Next
    If O.Contains(MyValue) Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Here is what is in my registry

```
Key Name:          HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
Class Name:        <NO CLASS>
Last Write Time:   10/30/2012 - 6:19 AM
Value 0
 Name:            RtHDVCpl
 Type:            REG_SZ
 Data:            C:\Program Files\Realtek\Audio\HDA\RAVCpl64.exe -s

Value 1
 Name:            Kernel and Hardware Abstraction Layer
 Type:            REG_SZ
 Data:            KHALMNPR.EXE

Value 2
  Name:            AdobeAAMUpdater-1.0
  Type:            REG_SZ
  Data:            "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\OOBE\PDApp\UWA\UpdaterStartupUtility.exe"

Value 3
  Name:            TortoiseHgOverlayIconServer
  Type:            REG_SZ
  Data:            C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\TortoiseHgOverlayServer.exe

Value 4
  Name:            Logitech Download Assistant
  Type:            REG_SZ
  Data:            C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe C:\Windows\System32\LogiLDA.dll,LogiFetch
```

Comment: Crashes with what error? Are you running your program as an Administrator? You are opening am HKLM key for write - usually you need to be elevated for that to work.

Comment: It does not give an error, simple "stopped working"

Comment: The same code works very quickly on my machine. Can you browse to that part of your registry and see what is there?